# how to return always 5 index rows in php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a problem with returning specific rows of the array in PHP.

I need to always return 5 rows of data in my array so that I don't need to create logic on my view, and with this, I can just display it by using an index.

In my view, I need to display the top 5 users:

```
1. bob
2. alice
3. MARIA
4. dell
5. cheka
```

The 3rd row will always be the user which is log in. If there is no row 4 and row 5 the output should be:

```
1. bob
2. alice
3. MARIA
4. N/A
5. N/A
```

The same if there is no users above him, and if he is the only one user:

```
1. N/A
2. N/A
3. MARIA
4. N/A
5. N/A
```

this is the PHP code that I have currently:

```
public function GetUserRank(){      
      $results = $this->Transfer_model->select_all_ranking();

      for ($i=0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
        if ($this->session->userdata('id') == $results[$i]->id) {
            if ($results[$i]< 3) { // there aren't two people ahead of you
                // return rows 0 to 4
            }elseif ($results[$i] > -3) {
                // code...
            }else{  
                // code...
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the sample response:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => MARIA [lob_id] => 3 [current_rank] => 5 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => bob [lob_id] => 3 [current_rank] => 2 ) )
```

The response is already fixed in the query, so that is the actual order of the list of users and the response will likely to have 100 rows or more or it can be less, I just first need to select on my loop the `ID` of the login users then I will get the two above and the two below of the login user.

Can I do this on array? By doing this I can save time without doing any logic in my view part.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: _“the 3rd row will always be the user which is log in”_ - why? What if they are the very first user in the ranking? What sense does it make to show them in position three then? And show two n/a lines for ranks “above” them, which then should not actually exist?

Comment: You should sort your array, and place your has-to-be-in-third-place-for-some-weird-reason user into the appropriate position. Then limit it to a maximum of five, and loop over it in your template afterwards. Whether you put the n/a logic into your template, or create array entries for those upfront as well, up to you.

Comment: the main goal is, to let the user  knows who is the first two that is above and the last two that is below to him. if he is the only user then , the first,second,fourth,fifth index should be N/A. i know this doesn't make sense but this is the problem that i have right now. sorry sir for the confusion.

Comment: You can implement anything you want, just saying it doesn’t appear to make the most sense. Putting two `n/a` lines _above_ the user, when they are actually in first place - that implies that there actually were two achievable ranks above the user’s current position, which they just somehow did not yet qualify for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select elements before and after your user. Later just pad those arrays and lastly merge them.
Something like this:

```php
function findUserPosition($inputs, $userId)
{
    foreach($inputs as $key => $input){
        if ($userId == $input['user_id']){
            return $key;
        }
    }
}

function getResults($inputs, $userId)
{
    $userPosition = findUserPosition($inputs, $userId);
    $positionsBefore = 2;
    $positionsAfter = 2;

    $sliceAfter = $positionsBefore;
    $sliceBefore = $userPosition-$positionsBefore;
    if ($sliceBefore < 0){
        $sliceAfter = $sliceAfter - abs($sliceBefore);
        $sliceBefore = 0;
    }

    $elementsBefore = array_slice($inputs, $sliceBefore, $sliceAfter , false);
    $elementsAfter = array_slice($inputs, $userPosition+1, $positionsAfter, false);

    $paddedElementsBefore = array_pad($elementsBefore, $positionsBefore*-1, ['user_id'=>'N/A', 'score'=>'N/A']);
    $paddedElementsAfter = array_pad($elementsAfter, $positionsAfter, ['user_id'=>'N/A', 'score'=>'N/A']);

    $results = array_merge($paddedElementsBefore, [$inputs[$userPosition]], $paddedElementsAfter);
    return $results;
}

//---===EXAMPLE===---
$exampleInput = [
    ['user_id' => 100, 'score' => 5000],
    ['user_id' => 25, 'score' => 4535],
    ['user_id' => 236, 'score' => 3823],
    ['user_id' => 263, 'score' => 3612],
    ['user_id' => 134, 'score' => 3123],
    ['user_id' => 11, 'score' => 2412],
    ['user_id' => 84, 'score' => 2113],
    ['user_id' => 345, 'score' => 1635],
    ['user_id' => 133, 'score' => 1254],
    ['user_id' => 156, 'score' => 244]
];

function displayExample($results, $userId)
{
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($results as $result){
        if ($result){
            if ($result['user_id'] == $userId){
                echo '<tr><td><b>'.$result['user_id'].'</b></td><td><b>'.$result['score'].'</b></td></tr>';
            }else{
                echo '<tr><td>'.$result['user_id'].'</td><td>'.$result['score'].'</td></tr>';
            }

        }else{
            echo '<tr><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}


//DEMO 1
$currentUserId = 134;
$results = getResults($exampleInput, $currentUserId);
displayExample($results, $currentUserId);
echo '-------------';   

//DEMO 2
$currentUserId = 25;
$results = getResults($exampleInput, $currentUserId);
displayExample($results, $currentUserId);
echo '-------------';

//DEMO 3
$currentUserId = 156;
$results = getResults($exampleInput, $currentUserId);
displayExample($results, $currentUserId);
echo '-------------';
```